# Docker mysql 5.7 not starting on OSX

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run an laravel project on my computer using Docker. But, I'm having a lot of problem with docker-composer as I am not able to start mysql 5.7.

I have tried almost every solutions that I could possibly find on the internet, but with no success. My os is OSX High Sierra, PHP on computer  7.2.9, MySQL on computer 8.0.

Here is docker-composer up output:

```
mysql_1     | 2018-10-08T12:04:17.219821Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_1     | 2018-10-08T12:04:17.222410Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysql_1     | 2018-10-08T12:04:17.244905Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1     | 2018-10-08T12:04:17.251151Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysql_1     | 2018-10-08T12:04:17.281187Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4800!
mysql_1     | 2018-10-08 12:04:17 0x7fe4c8865740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140620593518400 in file ut0ut.cc line 942
mysql_1     | InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
mysql_1     | InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
mysql_1     | InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
mysql_1     | InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
mysql_1     | InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
mysql_1     | InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
mysql_1     | InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
mysql_1     | 12:04:17 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
mysql_1     | This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
mysql_1     | or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
mysql_1     | or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
mysql_1     | Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
mysql_1     | As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
mysql_1     | collection process might fail.
mysql_1     | 
mysql_1     | key_buffer_size=8388608
mysql_1     | read_buffer_size=131072
mysql_1     | max_used_connections=0
mysql_1     | max_threads=151
mysql_1     | thread_count=0
mysql_1     | connection_count=0
mysql_1     | It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
mysql_1     | key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68195 K  bytes of memory
mysql_1     | Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
mysql_1     | 
mysql_1     | Thread pointer: 0x0
mysql_1     | Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
mysql_1     | where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
mysql_1     | terribly wrong...
mysql_1     | stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
mysql_1     | mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0x5584defd5a6c]
mysql_1     | mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x479)[0x5584de901709]
mysql_1     | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x110c0)[0x7fe4c84430c0]
mysql_1     | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcf)[0x7fe4c6bcffff]
mysql_1     | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7fe4c6bd142a]
mysql_1     | mysqld(+0x628c7b)[0x5584de8d7c7b]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x12d)[0x5584df1a507d]
mysql_1     | mysqld(+0xfa2db1)[0x5584df251db1]
mysql_1     | mysqld(+0xfa33e8)[0x5584df2523e8]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_Z6fil_ioRK9IORequestbRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmmPvS8_+0x2b0)[0x5584df25b510]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0xce)[0x5584df21064e]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x4aa)[0x5584df1df89a]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_Z31trx_rseg_get_n_undo_tablespacesPm+0x143)[0x5584df183213]
mysql_1     | mysqld(+0x627def)[0x5584de8d6def]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x2f3d)[0x5584df1500cd]
mysql_1     | mysqld(+0xd6d933)[0x5584df01c933]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x4f)[0x5584de94c3df]
mysql_1     | mysqld(+0xb143d6)[0x5584dedc33d6]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x2f0)[0x5584dedc65c0]
mysql_1     | mysqld(+0x64ae16)[0x5584de8f9e16]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0xc71)[0x5584de8fb9d1]
mysql_1     | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7fe4c6bbd2e1]
mysql_1     | mysqld(_start+0x2a)[0x5584de8f20ba]
mysql_1     | The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
mysql_1     | information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
cpl-api_mysql_1 exited with code 2
```

Also, docker-compose.yml file:

```
mysql:
   image: mysql:5.7
   ports:
     - "23306:3306"
   volumes:
     - ./storage/data:/var/lib/mysql:cached
   environment:
     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead
     - MYSQL_USER=homestead
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
```

Content of storage/data

```
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff        56 Sep 28 12:25 auto.cnf
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff   3072597 Sep 28 12:25 binlog.000001
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 12:29 binlog.000002
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 12:32 binlog.000003
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 12:34 binlog.000004
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 12:37 binlog.000005
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 12:49 binlog.000006
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 12:55 binlog.000007
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 13:02 binlog.000008
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 13:03 binlog.000009
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 13:04 binlog.000010
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 13:17 binlog.000011
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 13:22 binlog.000012
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 13:28 binlog.000013
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 13:53 binlog.000014
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 15:04 binlog.000015
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 15:19 binlog.000016
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 15:20 binlog.000017
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 15:25 binlog.000018
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 15:29 binlog.000019
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 15:34 binlog.000020
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 15:49 binlog.000021
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Sep 28 15:58 binlog.000022
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Sep 28 16:00 binlog.000023
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff  25746958 Sep 28 16:36 binlog.000024
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff      1670 Sep 28 16:40 binlog.000025
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       408 Oct  1 16:58 binlog.000026
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Oct  1 17:12 binlog.000027
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Oct  1 17:14 binlog.000028
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Oct  1 17:20 binlog.000029
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Oct  1 17:36 binlog.000030
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Oct  7 15:30 binlog.000031
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Oct  8 10:23 binlog.000032
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Oct  8 10:28 binlog.000033
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Oct  8 10:30 binlog.000034
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Oct  8 11:33 binlog.000035
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Oct  8 11:43 binlog.000036
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       155 Oct  8 11:50 binlog.000037
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Oct  8 11:54 binlog.000038
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Oct  8 11:54 binlog.000039
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Oct  8 11:58 binlog.000040
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       178 Oct  8 15:21 binlog.000041
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff       656 Oct  8 14:57 binlog.index
-rw-------@   1 viktor  staff      1676 Sep 28 12:25 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r--@   1 viktor  staff      1112 Sep 28 12:25 ca.pem
-rw-r--r--@   1 viktor  staff      1112 Sep 28 12:25 client-cert.pem
-rw-------@   1 viktor  staff      1680 Sep 28 12:25 client-key.pem
drwxr-xr-x@  62 viktor  staff      1984 Sep 28 16:32 cpldev
drwxr-xr-x@   2 viktor  staff        64 Oct  8 10:10 homestead
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff      4046 Oct  8 15:21 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff  50331648 Oct  8 15:21 ib_logfile0
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff  50331648 Oct  8 15:21 ib_logfile1
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff  12582912 Oct  8 15:21 ibdata1
drwxr-xr-x@   8 viktor  staff       256 Sep 28 12:25 mysql
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff  31457280 Oct  8 14:57 mysql.ibd
drwxr-xr-x@ 104 viktor  staff      3328 Sep 28 12:25 performance_schema
-rw-------@   1 viktor  staff      1680 Sep 28 12:25 private_key.pem
-rw-r--r--@   1 viktor  staff       452 Sep 28 12:25 public_key.pem
-rw-r--r--@   1 viktor  staff      1112 Sep 28 12:25 server-cert.pem
-rw-------@   1 viktor  staff      1680 Sep 28 12:25 server-key.pem
drwxr-xr-x@   3 viktor  staff        96 Sep 28 12:26 sys
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff  12582912 Oct  8 15:21 undo_001
-rw-r-----@   1 viktor  staff  11534336 Oct  8 15:21 undo_002
```

Comment: Can you remove the config files from `storage/data` if u have any, rebuild the containers and run again?

Comment: There are a lot of files in storage/data, I m not sure which ones are config files
here is ls -l output in the answer

Comment: Try moving `auto.conf` out of that folder

Comment: I tried, but still same error.

Comment: is your database big? Btw did you rebuild the containers after moving `auto.conf` out of `storage/data` folder? If u didnt, please move it out fist, then rebuild containers and fire them up again

Comment: Database is not big, 300-400mb max. I moved config file once again, and rebuild containers and still error is there.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following commands:

```
#stop all containers before remove images
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
#remove all containers if you want
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
#remove all images
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
#remove all volumes if you want
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried that, but the outcome is the same. Still error.